# Adding Google Analytics to HTML code error

Tags: html, github, google-analytics

I'm trying to insert Google Analytics into my code via the HTML route. I have correctly created an Analytics account, configured my website to my Webmasters account, and have committed the changes onto my site. I also made sure to leave the Analytics code untouched to the point where I even left the line-spacing alone. The following snippet is the code in my HTML head (as I understand I am meant to do).

```
<head>
...
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-65362973-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
</head>
```

However, my site is a Github affair. Is it possible that this is the issue? Or am I missing a step that is less than immediately obvious? Any assistance very much appreciated!

Comment: You do not say if there is an actual problem. If you do not see data in the standard reports remember that it may take some 24 hours before data is processed, so there is a delay (you should see something in the realtime reports, though).

Comment: You're right about the realtime reports - I checked it on my phone and it displayed as such. 24 hours is quite a long time considering Google's resources - is that time frame based on personal experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is directly from the documentation.   My personal experience is 24 hours for a small site.   If you see data in the real-time reports its working.  If its a brand new site it can take 48-72 hours to show data.  Other wise the following is true

> [Data processing latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en)
>
> Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more
>   than 200,000 sessions per day to Google Analytics will result in the
>   reports being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to
>   reports and metrics for up to two days. To restore intra-day
>   processing, reduce the number of sessions you send to < 200,000 per
>   day. For Premium accounts, this limit is extended to 2 billion hits
>   per month.